# CSS drop down animation

Tags: drop-down-menu, css-animations

I have this nav bar and I want it so that the submenu has an animation when it is shown.. I have the code `-webkit-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;` that I want to use for it but I'm not sure on where to put it.... here is the current code I have:

HTML

```
<div class= "header">
            <a href="index.html"><img class="logo" id="top" src="images/logo.png" width="250px" /></a>
            <div class= "nav">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Services</a>
                        <ul id="nav1">
                            <a href=""><li><img class="imgcenter" src="images/Brand-Design-Circle-Blue.png" width="100px" /> <br>Brand Design</li></a>
                            <a href=""><li><img class="imgcenter" src="images/Brand-Online-Circle-Blue.png" width="100px" /> <br>Brand Online</li></a>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class= "social">
                <a href="www.facebook.com"><img src="images/facebook.png" width="50px" /></a>
                <a href="www.twitter.com"><img src="images/twitter.png" width="50px" /></a>
                <a href="www.linkedin.com"><img src="images/linkedin.png" width="50px" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

CSS

```
    .nav {
    position: static;
    float: right;
    width: 700px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}

.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav ul > li:first-child {
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #6db6e5;
}

.nav li {
    font-family: "eras_demi_itcregular", Arial, Helvetica;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.nav li:hover a:hover {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #6db6e5;
    color: #6db6e5;
}
.nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 23px;
}

.nav ul ul {
    background: #6db6e5;
    display: none;
    padding-left:0;
}

.nav ul ul li {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-right: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #666;
}

.nav ul ul li:hover {
    background: #666;
}

.nav li li { 
  height:130px; 
  -webkit-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
 } 



.header {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #666;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

I have it working when you hover over the submenu list items but want it to work when the submenu is shown.

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/V2FqP/

thanks

Comment: Put it on the elements you want to transition - the part that drops down

Comment: Also, you can't transition display, use opacity or height instead